# Why can't uninstall my will_paginate gem within rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, uninstallation, will-paginate

I tried to uninstall a gem and get the below error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Macintosh-3:haloror patelc75$ gem list -d will_paginate

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

will_paginate (3.0.1, 2.2.2)
    Author: Mislav Marohnić
    Homepage: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki
    Installed at (3.0.1): /Users/patelc75/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334
             (2.2.2): /Users/patelc75/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334

    Pagination plugin for web frameworks and other apps
Macintosh-3:haloror patelc75$ sudo gem uninstall will_paginate -v 3.0.1

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d will_paginate`

Macintosh-3:haloror patelc75$
```

Comment: You don't need to / should not use `sudo` with rvm. Try without the `sudo`.

Comment: Zabba, so simple but remove 'sudo' did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to / should not use `sudo` with rvm. Try without the `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

try "gem env"

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin11.0.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@matrix_shopping_cart
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/ram/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/ram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@matrix_shopping_cart/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/ram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@matrix_shopping_cart
     - /Users/ram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org", "http://gems.rubyforge.org", "http://gems.github.com"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
     - http://gems.github.com
```

GEM PATHS: is where gems are installed

```
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/ram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@matrix_shopping_cart
     - /Users/ram/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@global

gem uninstall will_paginate -i /dir/name/where/gem/is/shown
```

You can also check installation directory for that gem with

```
gem list -d will_paginate
```

ou can also manually uninstall that gem by going to that directory and removing the gem in terminal

Comment: I removed the 'sudo' from 'sudo gem uninstall will_paginate -v 3.0.1' and that worked as recommended by Zabba above. Thanks for the help anway, 'gem env' is a very useful command.

Comment: Sure. I did not notice that. "rvm" environment is anyways isolated (mostly and recommended) to the account used. :)